# Let $G$ be a graph. Let $k$ be the minimal degree of $G$. Show that $G$ contains a cycle of length $k + 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph. Let $k$ be the minimal degree of $G$. Show that $G$ contains a cycle of length $k + 1$.

Comment: At least $k+1$ right?

Comment: It doesn't specify that. It just asked for a length of k+1

Comment: in that case it is false

Comment: Okay -- choose the subgraph on $m$ vertices such that every vertex in the subgraph has degree $v$ then you can use the fact that every $k$-regular graph has a hamiltonian cycle proved by Nash-Williams

Comment: consider $K_{2,2}$ it has no $3$-cycle as it is bipartite

Comment: If I follow the procedure of the similar qs that you posted, what would i have to modify to take in account the different criteria for k?

Comment: What different criteria?

Comment: Would the answer be different if its asking for k>1 or just a minimum of k?

Comment: well, when $k=1$ the question makes no sense.

Comment: Ya, my teacher isnt the best

Comment: alright ill just follow what they did in the link you posted. Thanks